# Executing custom activity on Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I am creating simple pipeline in the data factory that should only run a custom activity. The deployment template for the pipeline looks like this:

```json
{
      "type": "pipelines",
      "name": "MyCustomActivityPipeline",
      "dependsOn": [
        "DataFactoryName",
        "AzureBatchLinkedService"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "[variables('api-version')]",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Custom activity sample",
        "activities": [
          {
            "type": "Custom",
            "name": "MyCustomActivity",
            "linkedServiceName": {
              "referenceName": "AzureBatchLinkedService",
              "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
            },
            "typeProperties": {
              "command": "cmd /c echo hello world"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Additionally I have created all the resources needed- the batch account with pools and the storage account. All the resources are in the same resource group and subscription. I try to trigger the pipeline using console command

```
Invoke-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactory "DataFactory" -PipelineName "PipelineName" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName"
```

I am getting this error:

> Activity MyCustomActivity failed: Can not access user batch account, please check batch account setiings.

Has anyone ever experienced such an error from ADF execution of a pipeline? The weird part is that all the resources have access to each other and are within the same resource group and subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the settings for the storage linked service used by batch linked service. Make sure the connection string type is SecureString